# QGIS main_angle() equivalent in Python?

Tags: python, qgis-3, bearing

I'm trying to add functions to a plugin, and need to find the bearing of lines (or 2 points). Using `main_angle()` I get `"NameError: name 'main_angle' is not defined"...`

Is there an existing function in Python to replace `main_angle()`? If not, the layer is metric, so I could use basic trigonometry to do it ?

```
dL = x2-x1
X = cos(y2)* sin(dL)
Y = cos(y1)*sin(y2) - sin(y1)*cos(y2)* cos(dL)
bearing_rad = arctan2(X,Y)
bearing = ((degrees(bearing_rad)+360) % 360)
```

with (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) as coordinates.

Comment: There are many answers in GISSE

Comment: What do you mean "Using main_angle()" ? Where did you see `main_angle` function before ? To replace which one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you mean the angle between 0° and 360° measured clockwise from North as in the image. `main_angle` is an expression function, not a PyQGIS function. Therefore, you cannot use it solely in a PyQGIS script.

[image]

You can use this script:

```
x1, y1 = 0, 0
x2, y2 = 10, 50

p1 = QgsPointXY(x1, y1)
p2 = QgsPointXY(x2, y2)

azimuth = (p1.azimuth(p2) + 360) % 360

print(azimuth) # 11.3099..
```

If you have a line geometry with two points, use this:

```
if geometry.isMultipart():
    points = geometry.asMultiPolyline()[0]
else:
    points = geometry.asPolyline()
    
p1 = QgsPointXY(points[0])
p2 = QgsPointXY(points[1])

azimuth = (p1.azimuth(p2) + 360) % 360
```